# Java get point location from angle change

Tags: libgdx, trigonometry

This may be an issue that I simply do no know the proper terminology to research the answer to this, I am pretty sure the solution is a function of trig.

I have a method which accepts an X/Y position coordinate and an angle in degrees.  It should return an updated X/Y based on the rotation angle provided.

For example, A point is usually located at x=0,y=2 (top middle).  Now I need to rotate it to it's side by 90 degrees.  In my mind I know it's location is now x=2,y=0 (middle right) but I do not know the equation to produce this.

I think I need to first determine the quadrant of the starting point, and then perform the proper trig function from there.  This is for a game I am developing using libgdx which is where the Vector2 object comes from.

I have come this far:

```
public Vector2 getPointsRotated(Vector2 startPoint, float angle){
    Vector2 newPoint = new Vector2(0,0);

    // determine the starting quadrant
    int quad=0;
    if((startPoint.x>=0)&&(startPoint.y>=0)){quad=0;}
    if((startPoint.x<0)&&(startPoint.y>=0)){quad=1;}
    if((startPoint.x<0)&&(startPoint.y<0)){quad=2;}
    if((startPoint.x>=0)&&(startPoint.y<0)){quad=3;}

    if(quad==0){
        // doesn't work
        newPoint.x = (float) ((newPoint.x)* (Math.sin(angle)));
        newPoint.y = (float) ((newPoint.y)* (Math.cos(angle)));
    }
    // ...
    // other quadrants also don't work
    // ...
    return newPoint;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Update:
I have been avoiding and returning to this problem for a few days.  Now after finally posting the question here I figure it out within minutes (for ppl using libgdx anyway).

Libgdx provides a rotate function for Vector2s
so something like:

```
Vector2 position = new Vector2(0,2);
position.rotate(angle);
```

works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I find rotation matrices are very helpful for this sort of problem.

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/54299/tetris-rotations-using-linear-algebra-rotation-matrices